# nodejs serve blob(base64) as image

Tags: node.js

I know there's two other similar questions, but mine just isn't working and I'm not sure why.

I'm trying to serve a blob image saved in base64 on a nodejs server.

It's just not serving and I have no clue why. If I comment out the "writeHead" part it shows the base64 like it should. I've tried it with `data:image/jpeg` and without. I've also tried converting it to a buffer. Just can't seem to figure it out.

The base64 image is less than 200 kb and is saved in a mediumblob

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong

```
app.get("/f/:id", async function(req, res) {
  r = await Files.get(req);
  if(r.err.code){
    console.log("error",r);
  }
  var file = r.res.file;

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    'Content-Length': file.length
  });
  res.end(file);
});
```

Here's what it looks like in the browser
[image: Here's what it looks like in the browser]
Here's what it looks like without writeHead enabled
[image: Here's what it looks like without writeHead enabled]

Note: the "viewPortSize" id element at the bottom is an extension.

Edit #1: Also on Firefox it says "the image cannot be displayed because of errors"
This must mean I've encoded it into base64 incorrectly right?

Edit #3: Actually it is saved correctly because if I remove headers and display it as html with an img and src it shows the image properly..now I really don't know what the issue is.

[image: firefox error]

Edit #2:Here's the app.js setup

```
// ==============================================
// Base setup
// ==============================================

process.env.TZ = "Etc/GMT"

const express     = require('express');
const session     = require('express-session');
const app         = express();
const port        = 3075;
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

app.use(require('express-useragent').express());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))

// Cors
app.use(async function(req, res, next) {

  let allowOrigins = [
    // removed for SO
  ];

  if(Config.Env === Environments.Local){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    req.session.language = req.query.lg;
  }else{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Config.FrontEnd.Url);
    var origin = req.get('origin');
    for (let i = 0; i < allowOrigins.length; i++) {
      const allowOrigin = allowOrigins[i];
      if(origin.match(allowOrigin)){
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
      }
    }

    var subdomain = origin.split('.')[0];
    for (let j = 0; j < availableLanguages.length; j++) {
      const lang = availableLanguages[j];
      if(lang.code === subdomain){
        req.session.language = lang.code;
        break;
      }    
    }
  }

  // if(Config.Env !== Environments.Local){
    if(req.session.language !== undefined && req.session.language !== "en"){
      Config.FrontEnd.Url = Config.FrontEnd.Url.replace("://", "://"+req.session.language+".");
    }
  // }


  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, auth-id, auth-token, x-csrf-token, _csrf");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PATCH, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});
```

Edit #4: If I send it like this(with the data part on it) , the image shows like it should. However the headers are not of an image. (if I change to image it goes back to the black screen)

```
app.get("/f/:id", async function(req, res) {
  r = await Files.get(req);
  if(r.err.code){
    console.log("error",r);
  }
  var file = r.res.file;

  res.end(
    '<html>'+
      '<head></head>'+
      '<body>'+
          '<img src="'+file+'">'+
      '</body>'+
    '</html>'
  );
});
```

Comment: If the 4th edit works, it would seem you have the whole `data:image/png;base64,xxxx` string in the DB? To use that in a `image/png` response, strip the `data:image/png;base64,` and convert the remaining image data from base64. The response and length should come from the result of that conversion.

Comment: @Matt if I remove the “data:image/png;base64,” from the blob it still shows a black screen

Comment: After converting the base64 string? `Buffer.from(base64string_from_file, 'base64')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the database stores a `data:image/png;base64,xxxx` string then it would need to be converted back to the binary data to be part of a response with a content type of `image/png` (like a regular image file).

```
const img_base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

const server = require('http').createServer((req,res)=>{
  console.log('got req', req.url)

  // Extract image data
  const m = /^data:(.+?);base64,(.+)$/.exec(img_base64)
  if (!m) throw new Error(`Not a base64 image [${img_base64}]`)
  const [ _, content_type, file_base64 ] = m
  const file = Buffer.from(file_base64,'base64')

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': content_type,
    'Content-Length': file.length
  });
  res.end(file);
})

server.listen(3132, ()=> console.log('hi', server.address()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matt. This worked right away. I really appreciate you explaining why it didn't work. Thank you thank you!!